# i cant make the image_url to load on local host please hlp

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, web-deployment

i am making like a demo website that sells fruits i am following a youtube tutorial by (code with mosh) his images loaded properly but my images wont other things like add to cart button and name of product loaded properly. i ghave added on one url i.e
( https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Orange-Whole-%26-Split.jpg )

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product, Offer


class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'discount')


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'stock')


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'products'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',
                  {'products': products})


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New products')
```

index.py

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ product.price }}₹</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my first django project and the images_url dosent load anything every thing works perfectly but but the images wont load.

Comment: `src="{{ image_url }}"` is not correct, `src="{{ product.image_url }}"` is what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="...">
```

To

```
<img src="{{ product.image_url }}" alt="...">
```

Comment: i love you man no homo from 2 days have been trying to fix it finaly worked after help from alot of people it worked thanks alot